# Tires have developed some cracking, are they ok?

Tags: tires

I recently had my car serviced after extended non-use, had a few mechanics look at it, ended up changing fluids and brakes. Neither mechanic mentioned anything about tires, which I've bought about 4 years ago (they're Michelin Pilot Sport PS2 A/S with 50k expected life), put about 20k on them. Tires seemed fine to me too, and I passed safety inspection without any issues 2 days ago.

However, I'm letting a friend borrow the car for a couple months and she's concerned. One of her other mechanic friends is telling her that the tires are in bad condition and could explode. I asked her to take a few photos to get a second opinion, here they are. I wanted to know what you guys think.

[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: If your friend wants new tires on the car, maybe you can suggest that she buy them.

Answer (score 2):

The rubber is actually perishing around the tread area and also the bead. It also looks like there is perhaps some initial tread separation issue appearing here too, however this would be rather unusual on genuine brand tyres that are only 4 years old. 
I would suggest these tyres are replaced as the potential for failure is much higher with aged/perished rubber.

Answer (score 1):

It is very hard to see the tread completely, but from what I can see, there isn't a whole bunch there. The dry rotting on the tire is bad enough. That in and of itself would incline me towards replacement. Seeing as how the tires are seemingly so tread bare would only reinforce the notion.

Really, these tires look shot. But the images may be deceiving.

Comment: Yeah, those things look pretty tore up.